# Why do we need github.com/bitcoin-core, when we already have github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin?

Tags: bitcoin-core-development

There is already github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin, so why do we need to have github.com/bitcoin-core?

The GUI bit is stored in github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin under the qt section, so I don't see why we need to have a separate repository under github.com/bitcoin-core for the GUI.

Answer (score 2):

The bitcoin-core GitHub organization was created to contain ancillary repositories that were related to the Bitcoin Core software but not necessarily Bitcoin itself. These were for more project specific things such as developer documentation/wiki, reproducible build signatures, assets involved in quality assurance, etc.

Over time it has become the default place to put new repositories that are related to Bitcoin Core and are otherwise developed by Bitcoin Core contributors who want it those projects to be under the Bitcoin Core banner, such as the secp256k1 library, HWI, btcdeb, etc.

Since new repos are generally made in the bitcoin-core organization, the repo for GUI issues and PRs was also made there.

---

Personally, I think we should move bitcoin/bitcoin to under bitcoin-core as well. GitHub actually has systems for moving repositories and providing redirects for everything so it wouldn't actually break any links.

Answer (score 1):

The Bitcoin Core branding and GitHub organization was only introduced in [2013](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/3408) and so presumably contributors and maintainers didn't want to move pre-existing repos (implementation, BIPs etc) to a new GitHub organization in case it broke links, external documentation and general familiarity with the location of those repos. However, new repos could be (and were) created under the new Bitcoin Core [GitHub organization](https://github.com/bitcoin-core).

With regards to the GUI, development and review happens in the [repo](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui) under the Bitcoin Core organization and code changes are only mirrored in the github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin repo. The GUI repo was separated out in [2020](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/19071).

Comment: Is bitcoin-qt the GUI for Bitcoin Core?

Comment: @EoinMcQuinn: Yes, although there is an alternative GUI being worked on that is a WIP https://github.com/bitcoin-core/gui-qml

Comment: Why did they move the bitcoin gui from github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin to github.com/bitcoin-core?

Comment: @EoinMcQuinn: It is discussed in that issue I linked to https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/19071